# Tandem double slit experiment (similar to quantum eraser in setup)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment

Say you have two double slit experiments, DSA and DSB. Each has a photon source and the work is expected producing interference patterns that would can be observed by only looking at DSA or DSB they do not need to be cross referenced like a quantum delayed choice experiment does.

If instead you use a single photon source and then did a spontaneous parametric down-conversion to produce two entangled photons and ran one through DSA and one through DSB would they still produce an interference pattern observable without referencing the other?

I assume so because we are not making any measurements until they reach the final sensor that only indicates position, like in the basic double slit experiment.

Comment: You can’t get an interference pattern with one photon

Comment: yes they would. if you try and do anything to determine path ..... then no.

Comment: @PhysicsDave how can one photon produce interference? Detection is one photon at a time.

Comment: @BillAlsept He says use a "single photon source" .... i.e. he wants to fire them one at a time  .... not fire one photon just once.

Comment: @BillAlsept P.S. if 1000 scientists each fired only one photon in a DSE and then got together to map all the results ...... yes the pattern would emerge.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Yes I reread the question and of course they would create a pattern even with a single slit but the pairs of correlated photons wouldn’t have anything to do with it.

Comment: Thank you very much  @PhysicsDave .   That helps.

Comment: To clarify for @BillAlsept ,   Think of it as 2 different experiments, each should produce it's own interference pattern independently.  The only point of the entangled photon source is to tie together interference pattern breaking.

Comment: @KenHorne What is interference pattern breaking? And what is its purpose?